# Groupby Level Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, spyder

I am trying to understand the Groupby function in Pandas using the level argument in Spyder.

```
   def print_groups(groupobject):
        for name, group in groupobject:
            print (name)
            print (group.head())
```

I have data pertaining to a two symbols starting in Jan 2012 going right up to December 2012. I have set the index to Symbol, Year, and Month for the variable mi.

```
mi = s4g.set_index(['Symbol','Year','Month'])
mi
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is use the group(level=0) argument and find that only the first five rows of the dataset appear when I run this line of code.

```
mig_11 = mi.groupby(level=0)
print_groups(mig_11)
```

[image]

I find the same thing happening when I use level = 1.

```
mig_11a = mi.groupby(level=1)
print_groups(mig_11a)
```

[image]

Even when I change it to level = 2, I still see the first 5 rows.

```
mig_11b = mi.groupby(level=2)
print_groups(mig_11b)
```

[image]

Second Pic of mig_11b
enter image description here

[image]

I just don't understand why I see the first five rows for each of these groupby levels when the original data goes right up to December.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First of all... What is `print_groups` doing?

Comment: Oops. I didn't realise I had forgotted that part. I will amend my question.

Comment: Hello @coldspeed . I have amended my question.

Comment: Change `print (group.head())` to `print (group)`... right?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @coldspeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @coldspeed.

I need to replace print (group.head()) to print (group)  in the code below to see the entire dataset.

```
def print_groups(groupobject):
    for name, group in groupobject:
        print (name)
        print (group.head())#Replace with print (group)
```